# watchPosition do not reset highaccuracy after clearwatch

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I'm using watchPosition on a small application and I'm using both high accuracy positioning (GPS) and Coarse Positioning (Network based) to limit battery consumption.

To enable coarse positioning, I use following command :

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false });`
```

and To enable Fine Positioning :

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false });
```

To reset watching, I using clearWatch :

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
```

Strange thing is that after enabling Fine positioning, I cannot switch back to coarse positioning (GPS icon on android is still on).

for example :

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false }); // GPS icon is off which is OK

navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID); //GPS icon still off (OK)

watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true }); // GPS icon become on (which is OK)

navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID); //GPS icon become off (OK)

watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false }); // GPS icon is on which is **NOT OK**
```

I'm using Android 5.1.1.

Full example code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", WatchCoarse, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function WatchCoarse() {
        // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
        // device.
        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: false };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false });
    }

    function WatchFine() {
        // Get the most accurate position updates available on the
        // device.
        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                            '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
    }

    // clear the watch that was started earlier
    //
    function clearWatch() {
        if (watchID != null) {
            navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
        <button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>
        <button onclick="WatchCoarse();">Watch Coarse</button>
        <button onclick="WatchFine()">Watch Fine</button>
  </body>
</html>
```